# How to obtain Facebook user access token using new Facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

We intend to switch to Facebook PHP SDK 4.0.0 using Graph API v.2.2. I am very new to this new Facebook SDK and I am playing around it a bit. In this moment I am trying to get the privileges, like this:

```
/* PHP SDK v4.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appID, $appSecret);
$session = new Facebook\FacebookSession($accessToken);
/* PHP SDK v4.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me/permissions'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

This is working wonderfully, if I have the correct `$appID`, `$appSecret` and `$accessToken` values. For `$appID` and `$appSecret` I see no problem, because they are application-level settings, obtained from the developers page. However, I am struggling about how to get the `$accessToken`. I have been testing with a user who has a valid facebook access token and I have read the value from the database, but I wonder how could I obtain the following logic:

- read access token from database if existent
- check the validity of the access token
- if it is invalid, obtain a new access token
- request for long-lived access token
- set the value of `$accessToken` to the valid access token obtained from either the database or, if invalid/inexistent, obtained via Facebook SDK.

Note, that I have no problems using the database, so we can skip the steps of loading/storing the access token from/into the database. Does anybody know how can I implement this?

Comment: `FacebookSession` class has a method `getToken` – so once you’ve gone through the login flow successfully, it will give you the user’s access token. As for checking if a token is still valid, it has a `validate` method as well.

Comment: I have seen the method, but in the case I am working with, the user is already logged into Facebook. Do I really need to log in to get the already valid access token? I was thinking that it would be better to not log in to Facebook if the user has already logged in.

Comment: Let's suppose I have an access token read from the database. I would like to check its validity and if it is no longer valid, obtain a new facebook user access token. Is this impossible without logging in all the time using facebook?

Comment: Of course checking the token for validity is possible without logging in, you just have to create a session using that token. And btw., if the user already logged in to your app once, then on subsequent calls to the login dialog they will be redirected straight back from Facebook to your app, without any additional user interaction required (as long as they are logged in to Facebook itself.)

Comment: Can you add your ideas as an answer? I have tested them and they worked. Let us help people in the future having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`FacebookSession`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/4.0.0) class has a method `getToken` – so once you’ve gone through the login flow successfully, it will give you the user’s access token. As for checking if a token is still valid, it has a `validate` method as well.
And checking the token for validity is possible without logging in, you just have to create a session using that token.

And btw., if the user already logged in to your app once, then on subsequent calls to the login dialog they will be redirected straight back from Facebook to your app, without any additional user interaction required (as long as they are logged in to Facebook itself.)